# НЕ могу понять, как сменить цвет в js?

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование

Есть скрипт
`https://widget.blackairpods.ru/new2.js`

Не могу понять почему не меняется цвет у наушников а только у кейса,
Пример есть выбрать AirPods Pro

`project1635780.tilda.ws/testpage`

Не могу понять в какой части кода заменяется путь к папке для смены картинки наушника, по сути наушники должны выбираться из той же папки что основная картинка, но всегда берутся из дефолтной ( речь идет о папке v1, v2, v3 для картинок)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит в функции `buildImageUrl` по условию `type != 'case'`. Код в этой функции, вероятно, устарел, и его следует изменить.

```js
function buildImageUrl(type, color, modifier) {
  var color_title = color.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + color.title.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  var old = $('input[name=heromantor-widget-model]').first().prop('checked');
  var last = $('input[name=heromantor-widget-model]').last().prop('checked');
  var prefix;
  if (type != 'case' || old) {
    prefix = 'v1'; // вот здесь
  } else if (last) {
    prefix = 'v3';
  } else {
    prefix = 'v2';
  }
  return remote_url + '/new-img/' + prefix + '/' + color_title + '/' + type + '_' + color.group.title.toLowerCase() + '_' + color_title + '.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Не подскажите какое условие нужно чтобы и наушники менялись?

Comment: @Aleksys Наверное, заменить `if (type != 'case' || old) {` на `if (old) {`. Но Вы, я думаю, слишком верите в мои способности :).

Comment: Вы просто спасли меня!

Comment: Но теперь не меняется если переходишь с 3 варианта на второй

Comment: @Aleksys Я не удивлен :(. Функцию явно надо переписать/обновить. Это я вслепую выстрелил, у меня нет ни разметки, ни папок, ни картинок в них. Главное, Вы знаете теперь, в каком направлении работать.

Comment: А иерархия простая для картинок v1 для первого варианта v2 для второго v3 для третьего

Comment: @Aleksys Слова "первый, второй и третий варианты" мне ни о чем не говорят.

Comment: Речь о выборе модели
v1 папка для Airpods 2,
v2 для Airpods2 c беспроводной зарядкой,
v3 AirpodsPro

Comment: @Aleksys Ну, добавьте `console.log(old, last, prefix);` перед `return ...;`  и посмотрите какие значения у этих переменных при разных выбранных радио-кнопках.

Comment: Да все оказалось, что в папке v2 нет картинок, и все нормально работало